# Getting raw sql from sequelize tagged template

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize tagged templates to create queries.

I'd like to be able to get the sql they would generate without running the query. How would I do that?

Here is a simplified example

```js
import { sql } from '@sequelize/core'

const userId = 1
const query = sql`select * from users where id = ${userId}`
```

I'd like to be able to get the sql generated out of this:

```sql
select * from users where id = 1
```

How do I do this?